Identify movie about 18yo drug dealer living with his widowed father
I don't remember this movie exactly, so.. what I remember is this.
A movie about a guy  (18 or something like that) who his mother dies (I guess cancer) but his father is alive and they live in the same apartment I guess, then he start to sell some kind of drugs (he is just seller, he doesn't use drugs).
Then he some day goes to a party in someone's house "a fancy house", a party of boys and girls (I guess from school) but he doesn't have friends, I guess he went there just to sell more drugs.
Wait, I remember that he met a girl who he liked, and maybe she invited him to the party، or he invited her.. I don't remember ..
So, if any one knows what movie is this, please tell me. 

Can you provide any more context? When and where did you see the film? Was it an English language film? What culture/country? Is it meant to be a drama, a comedy? Every detail helps.

Could it be Twelve?, narrated by Kiefer Sutherland and starring Emma Roberts, 50 Cent and Chance Crawford?


The film opens during Spring Break on the Upper East Side. White Mike
  (Chace Crawford), once a wealthy, carefree teenager, now struggles to
  scrape out a living as a pot dealer, dealing to his former classmates.
  His mother died from breast cancer a year prior to the events of the
  film, her treatment having completely consumed his family's wealth,
  and left a deep emotional trauma on Mike.

A large scene appears to take place at a party:

Several of the other young residents of the wealthy Manhattan scene
  are introduced at a party as customers of White Mike, including Tobias
  (Nico Tortorella), a male model, and several others, all of whom know
  the attractive and popular Sara Ludlow (Esti Ginzburg). The party is
  held at the home of Yvette Vasquez & Chris Kenton (Rory Culkin), a
  hopeless nerd, but the host of the party, which he threw in order to
  boost his popularity.

From the cast description:

Chace Crawford [plays] Michael "White Mike", a philosophical 17-year-old
  drug dealer who roams the streets of New York, peddling marijuana to
  rich teens. White Mike is very intelligent and never uses drugs or
  alcohol.

So a lot of things fit - although I find no reference to the father.
